# How can i use the blockly event to implement multiplayer cooperation！

Tags: blockly, google-blockly

I've read the blockly's doc, i know that i can get the blockly event by

```
addChangeListener(event)
removeChangeListener(event)
```

these two functions. So i can get many types of blockly events, but how can i use these events to create a block.

So the situation is that client A get the block events from the server, A need to use these events to create a block.

So how to do this? Anyone know it?

Answer (score 1):

personally, i've found this link to learn some thing abour the Blockly Realtime Collaboration: https://github.com/google/blockly-samples/tree/master/examples/blockly-rtc

this may be helpful, and i will update it if i find something more useful.